# How to predict the Revenue by using logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, modeling

This is how my Training dataset look like i want to predict revenue of the Restraunt

[image: Here is my dataset]

I have been told to use logistic Regression to predict the revenue of the restaurant how can i achieve this using logistic Regression what is the good tutorial for how can i achieve it.

Comment: Logistic regression is actually more of a classification technique (despite its name). Perhaps you meant [linear regression](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/250).

Comment: @AmiTavory ya i know Logistic regression is more of classification thats why i am confused how can i predict the revenue. i have been told to use Logistic Regression only given hint as Ordinal Logistic regression for continuous Y.

Comment: Revenue is not a binary variable. So logistic regression is not appropriate. I agree with Ami that you probably want to use linear or non-linear regression.

Comment: @MichaelChernick i do believe the same but my mentor is like i have to do it with logistic Regression only

Comment: If he is wrong how can you find a way to use a technique that is not applicable.

Comment: Revenue is a continuous variable. It is not binary nor ordinal. So you can't have a prediction model for a continuous variable with logistic regression or
 ordinal regression which do not involve continuous dependent variables.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks as i cant upvote your comment as i have started  using stackexchange today.

Comment: Ordinal logistic regression will be wrong here because revenue is not ordinal. If you look at the output of an ordinal logistic, you will see that it has an intercept for each level of the DV, that doesn't make a lot of sense here.  Also, it will be less powerful than linear regression here because it ignores the fact that the DV is a ratio scaled variable.

Comment: @AdibRajiwate Thanks but it is not important that you upvote.  Just show our comments and answers to your mentor!

Answer (score 4):

Revenue is a continuous (actually ratio scale) variable, so logistic regression is not appropriate.  You should look into (multiple) linear regression.

> I have been told to use logistic Regression to predict the revenue of
>   the restaurant

Who told you? Ask **him/her** to show you how!

When you have fitted a linear regression, you should criticize the model with residual plots and so on. If that shows problems with linear regression you can come back here and ask.

Answer (score 3):

**People, let´s not confuse the Logit model with the logistic curve itself.** Logistic curves can be used to model and forecast revenue. People do it all the time.

The Logit model is appropriate when you want to know the probability of a event, but what you want here is not that. You wanna fit your data into a logistic curve, estimating the parameters that best describe your reality.

The parameters can be estimated in different ways, but the most common is to use a computer program to minimize the sum of the square of residuals, the OLS estimator.

You can see a practical example here: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/ivytech-collegealgebra/chapter/build-a-logistic-model-from-data/

Comment: Could you please add an example (or link) where the logistic curve is actually used for modeling/forecasting revenue?

Comment: https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/896590.2008-10.pdf

Comment: This is also nice: http://eaas-journal.org/survey/userfiles/files/4_4_Logistics.pdf

Comment: Can you please add those to the original post, as an edit, and write a  short summary?

Answer (score 0):

Your advisor is mistaken. Logistic regression is not suited for real-value prediction; it is suited for dichotomous 0/1, true/false, etc prediction. While you could reformulate the problem to a binary problem (sales increasing/decreasing) there's no good reason to do so.

Even a cursory glance at the Wikipedia page for logistic regression will convince your advisor otherwise.

Comment: Not quite true as logit can be used to predict continuous probabilities between 0 and 1 for responses that are measured proportions. But that's not helpful either for revenue prediction..

Answer (score 0):

I can disagree with most comments at my risk.

In a more general setting, where a researcher would have a continuous dependent variable and binary independent variable, the logistic regression can be useful in a way, the the input can be the continuous variable and the output will be the binary (independent) variable. This modelling would contain the same estimate of the model but coefficient meaning seems tricky.

Comment: This seems to be a case with multiple predictor variables, many might be categorical, but we do not know what they represent. How would you use your proposal of "inverse regression" in such a case?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I agree with that. Given that additional information about mentioned predictor variables is not available, I would treat them as nomical-scale categories, and in this case I should create a matrix design where all categorical interactions are encoded in a dummy binary matrix. Then I can use linear regression straight way, or one-vs-rest logistic regression inversely (to get coefficitns for each dummy variable). But this is rather a mind exercise anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Logistic Regression is a classification Algorithm of Machine Learning. With Logistic Regression, we can predict binary classification problems(0 or 1). From your snapshot of dataset as far as I saw you want to predict revenue of the Restraunt which contains real values. To predict this type problems you have to use Regression type Algorithm such that [`Linear Regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) , [`Support Vector for Regression (SVR)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) , [`Decision Tree Regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression.html), [`Random Forest Regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)  , [`Bayesian Ridge Regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_bayesian_ridge.html), [`BayesianRidge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html) etc.

Comment: On your first sentence, not necessarily: (1) logistic regression was around long before "machine learning" was anybody's phrase (2) more importantly here the fact that it can be used for classification doesn't rule out other uses. Often scientists and others are much more interested in predicted probability of an event as it varies with predictors. In particular, it is perfectly possible for logistic regression to predict probabilities all near 1 in practice **or** all near 0 in practice, but the pattern of variation with predictors may be what is of more interest.